# Altered Table not adding Column (pymssql)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I am using pymssql and i have a very simple add column statement. When i run the statement i get no error. If i run the same statement that i print out, in ms sql management studio, the column gets added.

```
table = 'tableName'
cmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + table + ' ADD temp FLOAT NULL'
print(cmd)
cursor.execute(cmd)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pymssql does not automatically commit every statement you run.

> **Connection.commit()**
>
> Commit current transaction. You must call this method to persist your data if you leave autocommit at its default
>   value, which is False.

http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#connection-object-methods

So the ALTER TABLE is probably getting rolled back when your program ends.